# Get the Mifare Keys (A & B) using ACS Smart Card Reader

Tags: java, android-studio, nfc, mifare

I've been struggling for a week in this part, I can open the reader, detect the card. but my problem is to get the key of a mifare classic 1k card.

I read all the documentations for it but I can't find how to do it.

This is the model of the card: ACS ACR1251 Dual Reader.

Any information or Idea on how to get the key of a Mifare classic 1k on this reader will be a big help

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You don't read the keys from the card, you send them to the cards.  The keys are needed to decrypt the data.  You could try one of the default values are commonly used for Mifare Classic cards:

```
ffffffffffff
a0b0c0d0e0f0
a1b1c1d1e1f1
a0a1a2a3a4a5 
b0b1b2b3b4b5
4d3a99c351dd 
1a982c7e459a
000000000000 
d3f7d3f7d3f7
aabbccddeeff
```